What’s the difference between normal ZZ plant and “Raven” on the DNA?
I didn’t find about it on Google. Does anyone know or guess about that?
I’m thinking maybe it would be the same as the difference between green algae and red one but I don’t know if they don’t have the same pigments molecule.
And I also assume that they originally have like the anthocyanin but it just didn’t express.
I really want to know what causes mutation of black from greens or what the mutation caused the difference on DNA.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I assume you want to know the gene that causes the Raven variety 's distinctive black-purple coloration and how the gene make the leaves black. Firstly the color may be coded for by several different genes, not just a single gene. Secondly, the changed genes turn the leaves black by causing the plant to produce large amounts of a dark pink-purple pigment - most likely an anthocyanin.
